# ruby add data to POST Request body as Formdata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, request, http-post

I am working on an implementation where I need to call a POST web-service which expects body as form-data. So when I test from PostMan app I select 'Body' then 'form-data' and enter my two keys and their values to make the call.
  This can be done in Java using `jersey-media-multipart` library and then doing something like this `MultiPart mp = new MultiPart(); 
FormDataBodyPart my_form_data1 = new FormDataBodyPart("my_key1", inputStream1,
 inputType1);

mp.addBodyPart(my_form_data1)` .

However from my first Ruby on Rails project unsure how this can be accomplished.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby class Net::HTTP can post form data. Documentation is here https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html.

For example

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => ['ruby', 'perl'], 'max' => '50')
puts res.body
```

If you are using PostMan you can copy the command as curl and recreate it with Ruby code.  For example, if you receive the following curl command form PostMan

curl -X POST \
  https://example.com/somthing/somthing/hay-now \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: cabfef34-17b1-43b5-bb95-ac7a9ec35bcb' \
  -d test=testvalue``

You can recreate the curl command like so.

```
require 'net/http'    

uri = URI('https://example.com/somthing/somthing/hay-now')
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    request. content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    request.set_form_data('test' => 'testValue')
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
      response = http.request(request)
    end
```

Please note, this is just an example.

Comment: Thanks. But the same documentation also says Net::HTTP doesn't support multipart post. My curl command from postMan has files in it as -filename 'blah.json' etc.

Comment: I have a Java code which does works fine by passing the json as a String. What would be its Ruby equivalent? `        final FormDataBodyPart myFormData1 = new FormDataBodyPart("myData", myDataJsonAsString,
                javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);'

Comment: Hello,   i believe you would set the content type to "content_type = 'multipart/form-data'" and read the file into the body request.body = File.read('your file here')